# How to generate a dictionary in swift from an array

Tags: ios, swift, function, dictionary

```
var tempsArray = [65,62,63,64,67,68,69,68,67,65,63,65,65]

func createCoordinates(temps: [Int]) -> Dictionary<Int, Int> {
    var tempCoordinates = [Int: Int]()

    for temperature in temps {
        tempCoordinates[temperature] = temps[temperature]
    }

    return tempCoordinates
}

createCoordinates(tempsArray)
```

The goal is a function that takes an array of Ints as its only parameter and returns a dictionary of coordinates. In this case the goal is (0:65,1:62,2:63,...)

My code is not executing and is giving me an error of "Array index out of range"

Comment: You know that a dictionary keyed by an integer from 0..n is effectively an array right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy to achieve with `enumerate()`:

```
let tempsArray = [65,62,63,64,67,68,69,68,67,65,63,65,65]

var dict = [Int:Int]()
for (index, value) in tempsArray.enumerate() {
    dict[index] = value
}

print(dict)
```

Result:

> [12: 65, 10: 63, 5: 68, 7: 68, 0: 65, 11: 65, 3: 64, 2: 63, 4: 67, 9: 65, 6: 69, 8: 67, 1: 62]

*Remember that dictionaries are unordered collections.*

I believe it will be easy for you to adapt this simple example to your needs. If not, tell me where you're stuck and I'll help.

Comment: I solved this issue almost immediately after posting it with a pretty similar approach to yours. I'm having trouble implementing the sort method on my dictionary and trying to rely on the swift language reference but it might as well be written in Mandarin.

Comment: After revising my code, I've solved my own issue, thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

More simple form:

```
tempsArray.reduce([Int:Int]()) {
    (var d, v)->[Int:Int] in
    d[d.count] = v
    return d
}
```